# How can I call an "if includes" statement, but break as soon as the text is found?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, search, break

I want to do something like this:

```
var x = "";
if (string.includes("hello")) {
     stop searching as soon as "hello" is found
     x += string; 
}
```

I'm working in javascript and I'm trying to speed up my project when it's ran.

Comment: java != javascript.

Comment: What makes you think that `.includes()` does *not* stop as soon as the string is found?

Comment: @Pointy I thought that because of how slow my project is running. But thank you!